# How to add an App ID to 'App Permissions'?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

An app ID is present in 'http:///_layouts/15/AppPrincipals.aspx' but the same ID is missing from the SharePoint Catalog's 'App Permissions'. The app ID can also be seen under 'Site App permissions' from Site settings. Can someone please let me know how can I add the app ID to 'App permissions'?

Thank you in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

SLS

Answer (score 0):

Goto  /_layouts/15/appinv.aspx and You will see the App ID and the title , get the APP ID and make sure my app principal has the proper permissions. In a PowerShell console with PnP PowerShell properly installed, enter the following commands
$ Connect-PnPOnline https://-admin.sharepoint.com -AppId  -AppSecret 
$ Get-PnPTenantSite

Comment: Look up by App ID doesn't retrieve the title, domain url and redirect uri. Can I give the same App ID and mention all the details manually? Please let me know what scope needs to be given in the permissions xml-Should be same as in manifest file or just the site collection scope?